# Animating tableView's height to fit its content on the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm building a tableView overlay embedded in a container.
The main goal is to make tableView animate its height to fit its content on the screen. 
After long hours of trials and errors, I figured the following, yet quite hacky way:

1) Reload the tableView when dataSource changes.

2) Update tableView's height constraint in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

3) Call `layoutIfNeeded()` in animation closure.

4) Set height of the container in callback.

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    let tableView = UITableView()
        // This callback is used to updater overlayContainerView height to match tableView's contentSize height.
        public var layoutCallback: (_ value: CGFloat)->() = { _ in }

    var dataSource: ModalCardOverlayDataSource? = nil { didSet {
        tableView.dataSource = dataSource
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        view.setNeedsLayout()
        }

        .
        .
        .
        .

        override public func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
            self.tableView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
                make.height.equalTo(self.tableView.contentSize.height)
            }

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
            layoutCallback(tableView.contentSize.height)
        }
    }
}
```

The solution works great but has one drawback: Whenever the height remains the same, the view animates down a bit, then return to the correct height on another refresh.

When I deleted animation code, the issue does not occur. I guess this is some inherent issue with UIKit.

The potential easy fix would be to introduce additional variable to keep track of tableview's height and when it remains the same, the animation code is skipped.
But I'd like to learn what is causing this issue.

```
override public func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        print("the height is \(self.tableView.contentSize.height)")
        self.tableView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
            make.height.equalTo(self.tableView.contentSize.height)
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            print("the height in animation is \(self.tableView.contentSize.height)")
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
        print("the height in CALLBACK is \(self.tableView.contentSize.height)")
        layoutCallback(tableView.contentSize.height)
    }
```

When I print the content view height while refreshing dataSource with the same content, this is what I get

**initial value**

> the height is 132.0 the height in animation is 132.0 the height is
>   132.0 the height in animation is 132.0 the height in CALLBACK is 275.33333587646484 the height in CALLBACK is 275.33333587646484 the height is 275.33333587646484 the height in animation is
>   275.33333587646484 the height is 275.3333333333333 the height in animation is 275.3333333333333 the height is 275.3333333333333 the
>   height in animation is 275.3333333333333 the height in CALLBACK is
>   275.3333333333333 the height in CALLBACK is 275.3333333333333 the height in CALLBACK is 275.3333333333333

**1st refresh:**

> the height is 132.0 the height in animation is 132.0 the height is
>   132.0 the height in animation is 132.0 the height in CALLBACK is 275.33333587646484 the height in CALLBACK is 275.33333587646484

**2nd refresh**

> the height is 132.0 the height in animation is 132.0 the height in
>   CALLBACK is 132.0 the height is 275.33333587646484 the height in
>   animation is 275.33333587646484 the height is 275.3333333333333 the
>   height in animation is 275.3333333333333 the height is
>   275.3333333333333 the height in animation is 275.3333333333333 the height in CALLBACK is 275.3333333333333 the height in CALLBACK is
>   275.3333333333333 the height in CALLBACK is 275.3333333333333 the height is 275.3333333333333 the height in animation is
>   275.3333333333333 the height in CALLBACK is 275.3333333333333

Any ideas what could possibly be causing such a weird behaviour? 
Why animation code makes it switching between two states of height depending whether it's even or odd dataSource reload?

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a subclass of your tableview and using autolayout in the StoryBoard. Inside subclass :-

```
import UIKit
class SelfSizingTableView: UITableView {

  override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
      self.layoutIfNeeded()
      return self.contentSize
  }

  override var contentSize: CGSize {
     didSet{
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
     }
  }
}
```

and also set tableview rowHeight to UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

Comment: I guess this is the common approach that can be found online - tried it, didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Have you callled cell.layoutIfNeeded in cellForRowAtIndexPath?